# « avoir du métal » vs « avoir des métaux » How do they differ in meaning?

Tags: pluriel

> Les gens ont du métal dans la tête. (de le métal = some metal)

I’ve just heard this sentence spoken, but considering that the noun "métal" can be pluralised into "métaux", shouldn’t you say "ont des métaux" instead if you want to say "some metal"?

> Les gens ont des métaux dans la tête. (de les métaux = some metal)

Comment: Without any context, it must be said that the expression itself makes no sense at all, so it's harder to answer your question. There's the expression *[mettre] du plomb dans la tête*, yes, but *du métal/des métaux dans la tête* ? Never heard that.

Comment: If the context is music, that would make sense just like say *Les gens ont du Jazz dans la tête*. There should be no plural here as Metal is a kind of music.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, in this story context the word "métal" means "metallic material" or "material made of metal", as in putting a pacemaker into your body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep the singular because *du métal* means here some amount of unspecified metal.

*Des métaux* implies you know there are different kinds of metal, like say copper, gold and steel. That might be the case with a dubious "head pacemaker" but this is not what the sentence is stating anyway.